# (Ionic 2) Keep auto play in slides when the slide is swiped

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, ionic2, swiper.js

i have the slider like this:

```
<ion-slides #promoSlider [options]="homeOptions" (change)="onPromoSlideChanged()" >
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let promo of promos">
        <img *ngIf="promo"  src="{{promo.image}}" style="width:300px;height:300px;margin:auto;display:block" >
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

I have use this options to keep my slide playing using auto play:

```
  homeOptions = {
    initialSlide: 0,
    loop: true,
    autoplay:2000
  };
```

But the problem is when i swipe the slider the auto play is stopped and the slider is not sliding again. How to keep the slider playing even i swipe the slider. I have try this code:

```
  onPromoSlideChanged() {
      alert('ABC');
      this.promoSlider.options = this.homeOptions;
      this.promoSlider.rapidUpdate();
      //What should i do in this method?

  };
```

What event i need to keep the slider slide again (keep playing) when i swipe the slider ? Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

You can find your answer here  => https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-keep-slides-auto-play-when-the-slides-is-swiped/54025/6

> The official docs reference the component Swiper as the base of the ion-slides component, so the API should be the same as the one described in http://idangero.us/swiper/api/11.
>
> You could use the option autoplayDisableOnInteraction to avoid disabling auto play after the user interaction.
>
> Your options array should be:
>
> ```
> homeOptions = {
>     initialSlide: 0,
>     loop: true,
>     autoplay:2000,
>     autoplayDisableOnInteraction: false
>   };
> ```
>
> Hope it helps.

Comment: the latest way is to include disableoninteration into autoplay:
autoplay:{disableOnInteraction: false}
https://swiperjs.com/api/#autoplay

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.images = {"status":true,"msg":"2 record(s) found","sliders":[{"title":"slider 1","content":"test
value","weblink":null,"image":"http:\/\/192.168.8.54\/test\/media\/mbimages\/a\/m\/test.jpg"},{"title":"Slider
2","content":null,"weblink":null,"image":"http:\/\/192.168.8.54\/test\/media\/mbimages\/
a\/m\/test.png"}]}

<ion-slide-box  delegate-handle="img-viewer" options="options" does-continue="true" loop="true" auto-play="true" slide-interval="5000" >

  <ion-slide ng-repeat="nt in images" ng-if="nt.slider_position == '1'" >
    <div class="box"><img ng-src="{{nt.image}}"  style="width:400px;height:200px;margin:auto;display:block"/></div>
  </ion-slide>

</ion-slide-box>


**Controller**

$scope.counter = 0;

$interval(function ()
                    {


      if($scope.counter == $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.$getByHandle('img-viewer').currentIndex() + 1)
      {



$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.$getByHandle('img-viewer').slide(0);

      }
      else{


$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.$getByHandle('img-viewer').update();

      }


             }, 2000);

angular.forEach($scope.images, function(value, key){
      if(value.slider_position == "1")
      {

      $scope.counter++;

      }
```

Comment: These Solution is for ionic 1 image slider.If you want ionic 2 image slider.I can give you

Answer (score 0):

Using **`Observable`** works for your scenario. You can use it as -

```
import {Observable} from 'Rxjs/rx';
// in class - 
@ViewChild(Slides) slides: Slides;

ionViewDidEnter() {
  //you get slider data from any web service
  this.sliderObservable = Observable.interval(3000).subscribe(x => {
        this.autoPlaySlider();
        // or you can do this, it will start autoplay at every 3 seconds
        // this.slides.startAutoplay();
   });
}
autoPlaySlider(){
    var slider_index = this.slides.getActiveIndex();
    if(slider_index < this.sliderData.length){
        this.slides.slideTo(slider_index+1);
    }
    else{
        this.slides.slideTo(0);
    }
  }
ionViewDidLeave(){
    this.sliderObservable.unsubscribe();
}
```

You can find more reference [***Here***](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-keep-slides-auto-play-when-the-slides-is-swiped/54025/9)